# Best SFX for hi tech futuristic environments?

Tags: library, sfx

Hey everyone,

In movies like Mission Impossible, and Die Hard 4.0 there are a TON of nice little technological beeps, whirs, servo's, and synthesised sounds that really make the whole thing sound very tech advanced.

What do you think is the best library for replicating these kind of beeps and tones?

I know there is the Hollywood Edge Hi-Tech SFX library - but being released in 2000. . .it's REALLY showing it's age and is quite poor by todays standards.

I'm looking everything from computer beeps. . .to key card swiping. . .to door air locks . . and ascending / descending computer noises and servos, but am having trouble finding a decent library!

Any particular favourites?

Answer (score 2):

Found this and it's exactly what I was looking for!

http://boomlibrary.com/boomlibrary/products/sci-fi

Hopefully this helps someone! :)

Answer (score 1):

This is something I purchased recently and find very useful for sci-fi stuff:

http://www.therecordist.com/motorz-elektrix-hd-pro-sfx

Answer (score 0):

you can also have a look at "Computer Noises"

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qCShxV7HghA

Answer (score 0):

I have just made a post to see if any sound desingers wanted to get involved on a grad film im making, Specifically to design sci-fi sound effects.

After a lock at the sci-fic construction kit I think i may be ok all by myself.

Thankyou!

Comment: "I have just made a post to see if any sound desingers wanted to get involved..." -> "After a look at the sci-fi construction kit I think i may be ok all by myself." = Priceless.

Comment: haha! yeah who needs sound designers eh? ;)